# Raspberry pi 1 B+ with Xenomai do not boot

Tags: linux

I try to copy the image of one Linux distribution which is given here: https://github.com/miquelraynal/real-time-rpi on my raspberry pi 1 B+

I copied it this way, as shown in the tutorial.

```
cp rpi-firmware/* zImage /media/${USER}/boot/
tar -C /media/${USER}/rootfs/ -xvf rootfs.tar
```

Unfortunately the raspberry does not boot.
I also redid the tutorial entirely but it did not work.
I think the image is not suitable for a raspberry pi 1 B + but a B.
Do you have an idea of what needs to be changed to fix the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As far as I understand the link at a glance you have to use Buildroot and compile the distribution. Do you compiled that distribution?

Comment: Yes I compiled the distribution and it seems to not have errors.
I also tried with the image given in the Github project.